# for loop in Perl

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [for loop in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531718/for-loop-in-perl)

```
use warnings;

my @a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

for $x (@a)
{
    print $x*=2;
    print "\n";
}

print "outside the loop \n";
print "@a";
```

Codepad link: http://codepad.org/D2Aa74nZ

Any operation on `$x` is changing the contents of the original array. Is `$x` behaving like a reference/pointer and not like a variable?

Comment: This is your second Perl question in rapid succession.
The documentation is a wealth of information not to be missed: http://learn.perl.org http://perldoc.perl.org

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is documented behavior in ["Foreach Loops" in perlsyn](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlsyn#Foreach_Loops). The loop variable is *aliased* to each element in the list that's being looped over. It's not like a Perl reference, but it's somewhat like a pointer if you consider that *every* Perl variable is really a pointer that associates a name with a piece of data, and a piece of data can be found by more than one name — for example `$x` and `$a[0]` — at the same time.

Comment: (The keys are right next to each other! Literally.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the loop variable is an *alias* to the contents of the looped-over array, and can be used to change it. This is what allows you to do stuff like `$_ += 1 for @numbers;`.

This feature is documented in [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) in the section on Foreach Loops.